# Javascript compare string after a replace function not work

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a piece of very simple code:

```
var b = "HelloWorld";
var a = b.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1');
alert(a);
if(a == "Hello World") {
 a += " yes";
}
else {
 a += " no";
}
```

a is always "Hello World" which is expected, but if statement cannot recognize it, and the result is "Hello World no".
This does not work if I remove replace function.

Any clues?

Answer (score 4):

Your replace puts a space before all capital letters, so there's a space before `H` and `W`. So this will work:

```
if (a == " Hello World") {
    a += " yes";
} else {
    a += " no";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actual result of your string after `replace` is `' Hello World'` starts with a space. Your regex inserts the space before all upper case letters.

Try compare with

```
if(a == " Hello World") {
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var b = "HelloWorld";
    var a = b.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1');
    var c = "Hello World";
    alert(a.length + ' ' + c.length);

    if(a == "Hello World") {
        a += " yes";
    }
    else {
        a += " no";
    }
```

The length of a is 12, and length of "Hello World" is 11.